# Reference controls within web service?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have an onBlur() function in a textbox which calls a web service.
The web service checks the email entered in the textbox against a SQL table to see if it's in there and if it is, I need it to deactivate an ASP Button. (Plus a bit more fiddly stuff, but once I crack the button all should be well). However, whenever I try to reference the button control (or any other ASP control) inside the web service I am treated to an error "Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from with a shared method..."

**How can I disable a button & change a panel's visibility from the web service?**

***onBlur()***

In VB.net

```
txtEmail.Attributes.Add("onblur", CStr(IIf(c.AccountNo > 0, "", "CallMe(this.id,this.id);")))
```

In Jscript.js file

```
//AJAX Call to server side code
function CallMe(src, dest) {
aForgotPwd.style.display = 'none';
var ctrl = document.getElementById(src);
var cont = document.getElementById(btn);
var panel = document.getElementById(pnl);
 // call server side method
return PageMethods.ValidateEmail(ctrl.value, CallSuccess, CallFailed, dest);
}

// set the destination textbox value with the ContactName
function CallSuccess(res, destCtrl) {
var dest = document.getElementById(destCtrl);

if (res == "") {
    if(aForgotPwd.style.display != 'none')
    { aForgotPwd.style.display = 'none'; }

    return true;
} else {
    setTimeout("aForgotPwd.style.display='block';", 1);
    setTimeout("dest.focus();", 1);
    setTimeout("dest.select();", 1);
    alert("We have your email address already in our database. Please visit forgot your password page");


    return false;
}
//alert(res.get_message());
// var dest = document.getElementById(destCtrl);
}


// alert message on some failure

function CallFailed(res, destCtrl) {
var dest = document.getElementById(destCtrl);
 return true;
}
```

***Web Service called by CallMe() function***

```
'Email Validation
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function ValidateEmail(email As String) As String
    Dim wbClient As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim strUrl As String =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WebsiteURLFull") + "/ajax/check_email_address.aspx?Email=" + email
    Dim reqHTML As Byte()
    reqHTML = wbClient.DownloadData(strUrl)
    Dim objUTF8 As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding()
    Dim output As String = objUTF8.GetString(reqHTML)
   If String.IsNullOrEmpty(output) Then
        exists = False
    Else
        exists = True
        btnContinue.enabled = False
    End If
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(output) Then Return String.Empty
    Dim c As GPCUser

    If TypeOf HttpContext.Current.Session("Customer") Is GPCUser Then
        c = CType(HttpContext.Current.Session("Customer"), GPCUser)

        If c.AccountNo > 0 Then Return ""
    End If



    Return output
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot acces page objects in the web service method, rather you can  disable the button and the visibility of the panel post the execution of the webservice in your call back function. Just return a message from your method which says email already present or new. Let me know if I am unclear.

**EDIT**
You can find further details of the webmethod implementation in this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
Public Shared Function ValidateEmail(email As String) As String
Dim wbClient As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim strUrl As String =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WebsiteURLFull") + "/ajax/check_email_address.aspx?Email=" + email
Dim reqHTML As Byte()
reqHTML = wbClient.DownloadData(strUrl)
Dim objUTF8 As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding()
Dim output As String = objUTF8.GetString(reqHTML)
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(output) Then
    exists = False
Else
    exists = True
    'btnContinue.enabled = False
    'Commenting the Button enabling
     output="disable"
     'Assinging the output as disable so that in JS you can disable btn
End If
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(output) Then Return String.Empty
Dim c As GPCUser

If TypeOf HttpContext.Current.Session("Customer") Is GPCUser Then
    c = CType(HttpContext.Current.Session("Customer"), GPCUser)

    If c.AccountNo > 0 Then Return ""
End If

 Return output
End Function
```

Also now in the CallSuccess before you continue with your functionality check whether the res is disable then you can disable button and display the already existing message.

Comment: Please explain as if I were a particularly challenged house plant. I've been butting my head against this mess for three days. It's my first dev job and I wasn't actually trained in VB so it's kind confusing to me.

Comment: Thanks! I get where you're coming from now. The CallSuccess() function already uses the output string as a usable result though. Can I not just jam it in there?

Comment: Also, somewhat related, because it's a separate .js file I know I can't use the server side code to get the client id ("<%=btnContinue.ClientID%>"). However, it's also not working if I use a static Client ID.